# Excel - return matches without blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

in Excel, I have a list in column A and a list in column B, and I want to find exact matches and return them in column C. I’m using
IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$1000,0)),””,INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$1000,0))).
However I want to do this such that in column C the matches are listed sequentially, e.g. 1st match returns in C1, 2nd in C2, third in C3 etc, rather than the matches being listed in the same row as the column A entry, as this process gives me a lot of blank cells in column C. Is this possible to do just with a formula? Any ideas greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can do:

```
=FILTER($A$1:$A$1000,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$1000,$B$1:$B$1000,0)))
```